# Flutter stuck on running xcode build not build

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm using beta channel, Android and Web version is currently running but when I run on IOS it stuck on Running Xcode Build. I waited 20 minutes and nothing happend.
What I tried:

- I changed beta channel to master, clean and upgrade
- I deleted Xcode/Derived Data
- Xcode Updated latest version
- Switched old build system

These didn't work.

**Flutter doctor -v output:**

```
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.53.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.19.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • 025247E3-C767-4FE2-81DB-6F10C7D45D5B • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 88.0.4324.146

• No issues found!
```

pupspec.yaml

```
publish_to: 'none' 

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  #State Managment and Many Thing
  get: ^3.24.0

  #Firebase Packages
  firebase_core: '0.7.0'
  firebase_auth: '^0.20.0+1'
  firebase_storage: ^7.0.0
  cloud_firestore: '^0.16.0'

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: have you looked into the build log?